# No CSS from include.php from level up directory

Tags: php, html, css, server-side-includes

I've searched around and found people with similar problems, but nothing suggested seems to work for me.

Here's my file structure...

```
CSS
  > style.css
INCLUDES
  > header.php
  > footer.php
IMGS
index.php
contact.php
about.php
terms.php
MUSEUM-PAGES
  > dummy.php
```

the **header.php** which contains the link to **css** works fine for any html/php page that isn't nested in a sub-directory.

But when I use a sub-directory to better organise the files it falls apart. In this example **museum-pages** > **dummy.php** can't bring in the css. The content from the header and footer work fine, just not the CSS files.

I tried replacing the

`<link rel="stylesheet" href='css/style.css' type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">` in the **header.php** to...

```
/css/style.css
.
../
../../
```

but it will drop all non-sub directed references in other pages, such as the homepage. I am baffled.
Anyone able to help me please?

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='/css/style.css' type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
```

The `/` is 'root'

**EDIT**

Since this didnt work, you could try this below, it isnt good practice IMHO however.. it will work.

```
<?php

// this is your header.php file

$linkToCss = "http://yoursite.com/css/styles.css";

?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href='<?php $linkToCss; ?>' type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
```

If that doesn't work there is another issue going on - try it see if it works.

Comment: @CallMePhilip is your website going to stay on one domain? There is an easy way to do it - but it isnt 'good practice' I will update my OP to show this

Comment: Yeah, I would think it would stay at www.museums-london.com — ?

Comment: @CallMePhilip give it a shot

Comment: Thanks, although I am working offline — presumably your technique only works online?

Comment: @CallMePhilip nope - you can link locally like so `"C:/path/to/css/style.css"` or if you are using wamp - `http://localhost/your/path/css/style.css`

Comment: — no joy. Just no styling at all.

Comment: @CallMePhilip odd, is your header file included in the first place? I have had problems like this before - try a control + f5 button push to do a hard refresh, if no joy move your CSS file temporarily into your includes directory to see if the issue is with locating your css file

Answer (score 0):

Use an *absolute* path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='/css/style.css' type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this didn't work either. It took away the css from the index.php file. I am truly puzzled.

Comment: Assuming your CSS file is accessible from `http://example.com/css/style.css` this will work. If not, correct the path in the `href`.